# OpenStreetMap XML to Object

Tags: c#, xml, openstreetmap

I have the below XML that I want to get specific values out of using `XDocument`. e.g. maxspeed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
 <meta osm_base="2015-01-15T20:26:03Z"/>
 <node id="1312239864" lat="50.5348877" lon="5.6286790">
  <tag k="highway" v="crossing"/>
  <tag k="traffic_calming" v="bump"/>
 </node>
 <node id="2025084665" lat="50.5345623" lon="5.6274183">
  <tag k="traffic_calming" v="choker"/>
 </node>
 <node id="2025084669" lat="50.5353414" lon="5.6303289"/>
 <way id="191950462">
  <nd ref="2025084665"/>
  <tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="secondary"/>
  <tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Rue d'Esneux"/>
  <tag k="source:maxspeed" v="school zone"/>
 </way>
</osm>
```

I have tried this

```
way.Tags = (List<OSMTag>)(doc.Descendants ("tag").Select (c => new OSMTag () {
            Key = c.Attribute ("k").Value,
            Value = c.Attribute ("v").Value
        }));
```

But I get an InvalidCastException.

Below is my Object models.

```
public class OSMWay
{
    public OSMWay (){}
    public List<OSMTag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class OSMTag
{
    public OSMTag (){}

    public OSMTag (string key, string value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "But I get an InvalidCastException." Where? What does the exception look like? Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: As a side note, you're using the `.Descendants ("tag")` wrong. By that I mean that what you're creating is not the exact structure of the XML. I don't really know what you're trying to achieve, but to me, it just seams that you shouldn't get _all_ the `tag`s from the document, but just those from the `way`.

Comment: The exception was the fact it wasn't yet a list. I had thought it was the attributes that were causing the casting issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an IEnumerable back:

```
way.Tags = doc.Descendants ("tag").Select (c => new OSMTag () {
        Key = c.Attribute ("k").Value,
        Value = c.Attribute ("v").Value
    }).ToList();
```

Should do the trick. A List implements IEnumerable but not Every IEnumerable is a List. The ToList() Extension converts a IEnumerable to a List

Answer (score 1):

It's not a list yet:

```
way.Tags = (List<OSMTag>)(doc.Descendants ("tag").Select (c => new OSMTag () {
            Key = c.Attribute ("k").Value,
            Value = c.Attribute ("v").Value
        })).ToList();
```